# Can't start Chrome Driver with saved profile on Selenium with C#

Tags: c#, google-chrome, selenium, cookies

I wrote a method to start clear Chrome Driver with different parameters, and it works. But when I was needed to start Chrome with my default profile (with saved cookies) - I wrote this lines of code, it runs browser (and I see my bookmarks, so it runs with cookies), but visual studio sleeps for a minute at return line, and throw me an exception. What is the problem here?

```
public RemoteWebDriver SetDriver(String Browser)
    {
        switch (Browser)
        {
            case "CH":   
                ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();                    
                options.AddArguments("--user-data-dir=C:\\Users\\user\\AppData\\Local\\Google\\Chrome\\User Data");
                return new ChromeDriver(options);
```

[image]

```
OpenQA.Selenium.WebDriverException was unhandled
HResult=-2146233088
Message=The HTTP request to the remote WebDriver server for URL http://localhost:52036/session timed out after 60 seconds.
Source=WebDriver
StackTrace:
w OpenQA.Selenium.Remote.HttpCommandExecutor.CreateResponse(WebRequest request) w c:\Projects\webdriver\dotnet\src\webdriver\Remote\HttpCommandExecutor.cs:wiersz 170
w OpenQA.Selenium.Remote.HttpCommandExecutor.Execute(Command commandToExecute) w c:\Projects\webdriver\dotnet\src\webdriver\Remote\HttpCommandExecutor.cs:wiersz 121
w OpenQA.Selenium.Remote.DriverServiceCommandExecutor.Execute(Command commandToExecute) w c:\Projects\webdriver\dotnet\src\webdriver\Remote\DriverServiceCommandExecutor.cs:wiersz 84
w OpenQA.Selenium.Remote.RemoteWebDriver.Execute(String driverCommandToExecute, Dictionary`2 parameters) w c:\Projects\webdriver\dotnet\src\webdriver\Remote\RemoteWebDriver.cs:wiersz 1177
w OpenQA.Selenium.Remote.RemoteWebDriver.StartSession(ICapabilities desiredCapabilities) w c:\Projects\webdriver\dotnet\src\webdriver\Remote\RemoteWebDriver.cs:wiersz 1114
w OpenQA.Selenium.Remote.RemoteWebDriver..ctor(ICommandExecutor commandExecutor, ICapabilities desiredCapabilities) w c:\Projects\webdriver\dotnet\src\webdriver\Remote\RemoteWebDriver.cs:wiersz 141
w OpenQA.Selenium.Chrome.ChromeDriver..ctor(ChromeOptions options) w c:\Projects\webdriver\dotnet\src\webdriver\Chrome\ChromeDriver.cs:wiersz 76
w AutoLike.Login.SetDriver(String Browser) w d:\users\documents\visual studio 2015\Projects\AutoLike\AutoLike\Login.cs:wiersz 70
w AutoLike.Login..ctor(String Browser, String URL, String DownloadPath) w d:\users\documents\visual studio 2015\Projects\AutoLike\AutoLike\Login.cs:wiersz 32
w AutoLike.Form1.button1_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e) w d:\users\documents\visual studio 2015\Projects\AutoLike\AutoLike\Form1.cs:wiersz 34
w System.Windows.Forms.Control.OnClick(EventArgs e)
w System.Windows.Forms.Button.OnClick(EventArgs e)
w System.Windows.Forms.Button.OnMouseUp(MouseEventArgs mevent)
w System.Windows.Forms.Control.WmMouseUp(Message& m, MouseButtons button, Int32 clicks)
w System.Windows.Forms.Control.WndProc(Message& m)
w System.Windows.Forms.ButtonBase.WndProc(Message& m)
w System.Windows.Forms.Button.WndProc(Message& m)
w System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.OnMessage(Message& m)
w System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.WndProc(Message& m)
w System.Windows.Forms.NativeWindow.DebuggableCallback(IntPtr hWnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wparam, IntPtr lparam)
w System.Windows.Forms.UnsafeNativeMethods.DispatchMessageW(MSG& msg)
w System.Windows.Forms.Application.ComponentManager.System.Windows.Forms.UnsafeNativeMethods.IMsoComponentManager.FPushMessageLoop(IntPtr dwComponentID, Int32 reason, Int32 pvLoopData)
w System.Windows.Forms.Application.ThreadContext.RunMessageLoopInner(Int32 reason, ApplicationContext context)
w System.Windows.Forms.Application.ThreadContext.RunMessageLoop(Int32 reason, ApplicationContext context)
w System.Windows.Forms.Application.Run(Form mainForm)
w AutoLike.Program.Main() w d:\users\documents\visual studio 2015\Projects\AutoLike\AutoLike\Program.cs:wiersz 19
w System.AppDomain._nExecuteAssembly(RuntimeAssembly assembly, String[] args)
w System.AppDomain.ExecuteAssembly(String assemblyFile, Evidence assemblySecurity, String[] args)
w Microsoft.VisualStudio.HostingProcess.HostProc.RunUsersAssembly()
w System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart_Context(Object state)
w System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
w System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
w System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
w System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart()
InnerException: 
HResult=-2146233079
Message=Upłynął limit czasu operacji
Source=System
StackTrace:
w System.Net.HttpWebRequest.GetResponse()
w OpenQA.Selenium.Remote.HttpCommandExecutor.CreateResponse(WebRequest request) w c:\Projects\webdriver\dotnet\src\webdriver\Remote\HttpCommandExecutor.cs:wiersz 162
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to quote the path since it contains a space character:

```
options.AddArguments(String.Format(
   "--user-data-dir=\"{0}\"", @"C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data"));
```

Comment: seems like this is not the case, because even with space character it starts browser. now it doesn't: 
`System.InvalidOperationException was unhandled
  HResult=-2146233079
  Message=unknown error: cannot create default profile directory
  (Driver info: chromedriver=2.30.477700 (0057494ad8732195794a7b32078424f92a5fce41),platform=Windows NT 6.1.7601 SP1 x86_64)
  Source=WebDriver`

Comment: You need the quoting. Otherwise `Data` is considered as an additional argument. This new error indicates that the path you provided doesn't exists  or that the account from which you are running the code doesn't have the permission for reading the folder.